# Why does map on textFile cause Compilation failed?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm running scala code from [this](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-frequent-pattern-mining.html) tutorial.

```
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
val data: RDD[Array[String]] = sc.textFile("pathToFile")
  .map(line => {
    val splits: Array[String] = line.trim.split(',')
  })
```

I get the following error:

> [error]  found   : Unit [error]
>   required: Array[String] [error]
>   }) [error]
>    ^ [error] one error found [error]
>   (compile:compileIncremental) Compilation failed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'v created variable but does not return it. Remove assignment to variable and you'll get expected data type.

`-val splits: Array[String] = line.trim.split(',')`

`+line.trim.split(',')`

Answer (score 0):

As Mr V says, you're not returning the value. Scala doesn't require an explicit return statement, and will return the last value in a function. In your case though you're assigning a value to a variable. If you get rid of that assignment, scala will treat it as the return value. This means you can make your code even terser:

```
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
val data: RDD[Array[String]] = sc.textFile("pathToFile").map(_.trim.split(','))
```

The `_` character in `.map(_.trim.split(','))` is shorthand for the parameter passed to the function - in this case it's the same as what you called `line` above.

You also don't need to declare the variable type, but when working with RDDs I find it a useful safety net to declare it. However, you can safely get rid of it from the map function since scala will typecheck that it returns something compatible with `RDD[Array[String]]` (which, as I say, is optional).

Answer (score -1):

Hi Bob try this way (as scala infer types)

```
val data = sc.textFile("pathToFile")
val splits =   data.map(line =>  line.trim.split(','))
```